# XMLHttpRequest Error Details

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How can the XMLHttpRequest error details be logged via Javascript when error event occurs? I could not find such a property of the error event. But when using developer tools of browsers, the developer tools supply the detailed information about the error. Is there a way to do this via Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener an output the event object.

```
request.addEventListener("error",function(event) {console.log(event);},false);
```

Comment: the event itself doesn't seem to contain any details about the error that happened